# Content toggling issue

Tags: jquery

I want certain info to be hidden by default and reveal it when clicking on the item. I grabbed a toggle script off the net, but for some reason it's doing the opposite of what I want.

Here's the script that goes between the head tags:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("p").click(function(){
        $("ul").toggle();
      });
   });
</script>
```

Here's the code in the body:

```
<p class="toggle">+ Apple iPad 2</p>
<ul>
  <li>Display Screen (LCD) Only Replacement - $99.99</li>
  <li>Top Glass (Digitizer) Only Replacement (Black) – $109.99</li>
  <li>Top Glass (Digitizer) Only Replacement (White) – $109.99</li>
</ul>
```

If someone could please explain what I'm doing wrong I'd really appreciate it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide after loading page, then toggle on click:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul").hide(); //added this line
    $("p").click(function(){
        $("ul").toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2L0efebh/1/

**JavaScript**

```
$("p").click(function(){
   $("ul").toggle("slow");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<p class="toggle">+ Apple iPad 2</p>
<ul class="unactive">
  <li>Display Screen (LCD) Only Replacement - $99.99</li>
  <li>Top Glass (Digitizer) Only Replacement (Black) – $109.99</li>
  <li>Top Glass (Digitizer) Only Replacement (White) – $109.99</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.unactive {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The toggle method toggles the visibility of elements. In your case you did not hide the **ul** element due to which initially by default all the elements are shown. Notice how initially the visibilty of **ul** is set to **display:none** which simply means the display property specifies if/how an element is displayed. By specifying the visibility initially we keep the **ul hidden** and as soon as the user will click on the paragraph the toggle function will toggle the visibility of the matched element and hence the **ul** will be shown to the user. 
Below is the code to make it work the way you want it

**HTML**

```
<p class="toggle">+ Apple iPad 2</p>
<ul class="inactive">
    <li>Display Screen (LCD) Only Replacement - $99.99</li>
    <li>Top Glass (Digitizer) Only Replacement (Black) – $109.99</li>
    <li>Top Glass (Digitizer) Only Replacement (White) – $109.99</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.inactive {
    display:none;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$("p").click(function(){
    $("ul").toggle("slow");
});
```

For understanding toggle function more precisely you can check [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)